# Google AMP Filter

Tags: templating, filter

[This](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/approaching-google-amp) is a great post about how to integrate AMP into your Craft CMS website.

What happens though if you have a standard 'img' tag in your existing content block?

I thought it would be neat to be able to set up a custom Craft/Twig AMP filter that automatically converts:

```
<img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="150" height="100" />
```

To:

```
<amp-img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="150" height="100"></amp-img>
```

By using:

```
{% block content %} {{ entry.body | amp }} {% endblock %}
```

Is there something existing that I could modify to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `replace` filter, it accepts regex:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I actually tried this but my regex was too weak. Any suggestions for my example?

Answer (score 1):

Just building on the answer from @khalwat, if you use the `replace` filter, your solution might look something like this:

`{{ entry.body | amp | replace(/(<img )(.*?)(\\/>)/g, '<amp-img $2></amp-img>') }}`

There may be cleaner regex solutions out there, but I think that one will cut the mustard.